# Plotly graph not displaying

Tags: python, plot, plotly

i'm just trying out plotly/dash and when i write the below code nothing gets displayed.. it's just a blank box. I've tried installing nodejs (i'm using anaconda) so  that i can try and install some extension ' jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/plotly-extension' but this does not work for some reason i cannot even install nodejs.

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
# Set notebook mode to work in offline
pyo.init_notebook_mode()
#init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
# Create traces
trace0 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[10, 15, 13, 17]
)
trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4],
    y=[16, 5, 11, 9]
)
# Fill out data with our traces
data = [trace0, trace1]
layout=go.Layout(barmode='stack')
fig=go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
# Plot it and save as basic-line.html
pyo.iplot(fig, filename = 'basic-line')
```

what else can i do to help view my graph?

Comment: `iplot()` *could* be the problem.

Comment: Did you install the plotly extension? And *why* can't you install nodejs?

Comment: @vestland i was unable to install the extension. I could not install nodejs as it says it is corrupted in my pkgs folders for anaconda.

Comment: i have also updated my jupyter notebook yet nothing

Answer (score 2):

I'd like some more info regarding versions of plolty, Jupyterlab etc, but `iplot()` could very likely be the problem here. Try another basic example like:

**Code:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
animals=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Bar(name='SF Zoo', x=animals, y=[20, 14, 23]),
    go.Bar(name='LA Zoo', x=animals, y=[12, 18, 29])
])
# Change the bar mode
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
fig.show()
```

**Plot:**

[image]

Let me know how that worked out for you.

Comment: hi this doesn't work - it's just blank :/ . i'm on jupyter notebook and plotly version '4.1.1'

Comment: i have been reading some forums and the above only works if i but fig.show(renderer="svg") @vestland however i do not know how to get iplot working

Answer (score 1):

When you run your code and the browser pops up, click in the address bar and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Google Colab have given instruction regrading Plotly

```
def configure_plotly_browser_state():
  import IPython
  display(IPython.core.display.HTML('''
        <script src="/static/components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
        <script>
          requirejs.config({
            paths: {
              base: '/static/base',
              plotly: 'https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-1.5.1.min.js?noext',
            },
          });
        </script>
        '''))
```

Call this function configure_plotly_browser_state()